Match digits in SourceSans3 with Mathematical Sans-Serif Digits in STIX Two
Consider the following MWE:
\documentclass[
   tipotesi=custom
]{toptesi}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setsansfont{SourceSans3-Regular}[       % https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-sans/raw/refs/heads/release/OTF/SourceSans3-Regular.otf
    Extension       = .otf ,
    BoldFont        = SourceSans3-Bold , % https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-sans/raw/refs/heads/release/OTF/SourceSans3-Bold.otf
    ItalicFont      = SourceSans3-It ,   % https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-sans/raw/refs/heads/release/OTF/SourceSans3-It.otf
]

\setmathfont{STIXTwoMath}

\begin{document}

\textsf{g10} \textbf{\textsf{g10}} \textit{\textsf{g10}}

\(\symsfup{g}\symsfup{1}\symsfup{0}\) \(\symbfsfup{g}\symbfsfup{1}\symbfsfup{0}\)

\setsansfont{SourceSans3-Regular}[
    Extension       = .otf ,
    BoldFont        = SourceSans3-Bold ,
    ItalicFont      = SourceSans3-It ,
    Numbers         = Proportional ,
]
\textsf{g10} \textbf{\textsf{g10}} \textit{\textsf{g10}}

\end{document}

Now, compile it:
latexmk --halt-on-error --file-line-error -lualatex ./foo.tex

Everything works! But look the result:

Adding feature PNUM I get the desired digit 1. Indeed, Mathematical Sans-Serif Digit One (middle line in the output above) in STIX Two hasn't the underline stroke. So to match SourceSans3 and STIX I added Numbers=Proportional. Anyway, another issue is risen. The new glyph (from SourceSans3, last line in the output above) has a different left/right side bearing and kerning. What can I do to solve this issue? Or it's better to ignore it?
Note that I chose SourceSans3 as sans-serif based on this (reliable) GitHub comment.
A possible solution is to use \kern before and after digit 1. But maybe there are some more general solution.
Edit
In STIXTwoMath Unicode blocks U+1D7E3..U+1D7F5 and U+1D5A0..U+1D66F contain math glyphs. I prefer using them only in math mode as TR25 suggests:

The Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols block (U+1D400..U+1D7FF) contains a large collection of letter-like symbols for use in mathematical notation, typically for variables. The characters in this block are intended for use only in mathematical or technical notation; they are not intended for use in non-technical text.

Fortunately, these glyphs based on Sans Source. So in text mode I want to use glyphs from this font. But digit 1 is different! Digging into luaotfload source code I found patch_cambria_domh. So I thought to create a patch_font callback to manually adjust (on-the-fly patch) side bearings of digit 1 from Sans Source. Another example from doc can be found here.

it isn't clear what you are trying to change. You have chosen different fonts for text and math so all the characters are different so why is it an issue if the 1 is different? If you want the same digits in text and nath simply use the same font in both cases, theer is no need to choose a different font then use font properties and manual kerning to make them look a bit similar
